# Taking a list and embedding operators for the creation of a dummy variable

Tags: pandas, list, operators, dummy-variable

I have the following df;

```
{'country': {18: 'Argentina', 19: 'Argentina', 20: 'Argentina', 21: 'Brazil', 22: 'Brazil'}, 'year': {18: 1998, 19: 1999, 20: 2000, 21: 1980, 22: 1981}, 'Inflation (Annual %)': {18: 0.4892870291442586, 19: 0.5072515700889069, 20: -1.4451253758139493, 21: 'nan', 22: 101.725072957927}, 'PostTreatmentYear': {18: 1, 19: 1, 20: 1, 21: 0, 22: 0}}
```

I would like to create a 'treatment' variable where it is equal to 1, if the country is a certain country, 0 otherwise. I have been sucessfully doing this as follows;

```
df['Treatment'] = np.where(df['country'] == 'Argentina', 1, 0)
```

Which works, appending a new column called Treatment, which is one for Argentina, zero for all other countries. There are several countries that I want to add to the treatment, but obviously when I repeat the code for the other countries, It turns the previously correctly set ones, to zero.

So I tried to create one line, with or statements, in order to avoid this. I did the following;

```
print(df.country.unique())
```

to get a list of all the unique country names, then I tried (a shortened example):

```
df['Treatment'] = np.where(df['country'] == 'Argentina' or 'Brazil' or 'Chile', 1, 0)
```

This results in the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My question is two fold really;

1. How to take a list and add operators between elements, in order to do

```
    df['Treatment'] = np.where(df['country'] == 'Argentina' or 'Brazil' or 'Chile', 1, 0)
```

more efficently, just taking my list from

```
print(df.country.unique())
```

in order to save time (as there are many countries)

2. How to correctly specify the operation here for (or one like it if this is incorrect

```
df['Treatment'] = np.where(df['country'] == 'Argentina' or 'Brazil' or 'Chile', 1, 0)
```

To get it to work as intended.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df['Treatment'] = df['country'].isin(['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile']).astype(int)`